# substr doesn't work fine with utf8

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, right-to-left, substr

I am using a substr method to access the first 20 characters of a string. It works fine in normal situation, but while working on rtl languages (utf8) it gives me wrong results (about 10 characters are shown). I have searched the web but found nth useful to solve this issue. This is my line of code:

```
substr($article['CBody'],0,20);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> If you’re working with strings encoded as UTF-8 you may lose
>   characters when you try to get a part of them using the PHP substr
>   function. This happens because in UTF-8 characters are not restricted
>   to one byte, they have variable length to match Unicode characters,
>   between 1 and 4 bytes.

You can use **[mb_substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php)**, It works almost the same way as substr but the difference is that you can add a new parameter to specify the encoding type, whether is `UTF-8` or a different encoding.

Try this:

```
$str = mb_substr($article['CBody'], 0, 20, 'UTF-8');

echo utf8_decode($str);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: woww  it worked for me. I really am thankful, I was searching for it about 3 hours. Thank again:)

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead, here is extra text to make the body long enough. This will handle multi-byte characters.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php