# Can't use substr to specify number of Hebrew letters

Tags: php, hebrew

In written Hebrew there are marks for vowels called niqqud instead of full letters. In English "a e i o u" are letters; in Hebrew they are marks under the letters. For example, in נִקּוּד there is a dot for "i" under the first letter (נִ) (Hebrew is read right-to-left). Each mark is a character but not a letter.

I am trying to get the last 2 letters (not characters) of any word in Hebrew. The problem is that the functions: `substr()` and `mb_substr()` include the vowel marker as a full character, and because of that it's not giving me the last 2 letters. What can I do?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $array = array('סָאוּנְדּמֶן','לֵיְמֶן','דֹּמֶן','דּוֹרְמֶן','אחמד','בןהמלך');
    $dynamicstring = 'שֶׁמֶן';
    $word_strlen = strlen($dynamicstring);
    $newstring = substr($dynamicstring, -4);

    echo strlen($dynamicstring);
    echo '<br>';
    echo htmlspecialchars($newstring);
?>
```

Comment: Please add the code of your attempts as weel

Comment: @DarkBee added thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [substr doesn't work fine with utf8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785682/substr-doesnt-work-fine-with-utf8)

Comment: @NigelRen no dude its not, my problem here is about the hebrew letters scoring. not same

Comment: @din Other than using `mb_substr`, you also need to use [`mb_strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) as well of course.

Comment: @DarkBee I am using strlen only for private check, after all, I do not have to use the length of the string

Comment: A bit confused about your question. In your code, what would be the correct answer? (the two last characters)

Comment: @JohnT here is the correct answer: מֶן

Comment: I've posted code that should be correct but it don't give the answer you wish. I don't see any reason it should not work for Hebrew but have to trust you that it don't.

Comment: @JohnT your code its worked absolutely in hebrew, but not with scored hebrew letters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [strpos return wrong position at hebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22976410/strpos-return-wrong-position-at-hebrew)

Answer (score 2):

You should use [mb_substr();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php). Make sure you also check the following:

- HTML document set to same charset
- Database connection to insert data set to the same charset
- Database table set to the same charset
- Database connection to fetch data set to the same charset

For Hebrew you should use UTF-8 as charset.

This should be the correct code:

```
<?php
    $array = array('סָאוּנְדּמֶן','לֵיְמֶן','דֹּמֶן','דּוֹרְמֶן','אחמד','בןהמלך');
    $dynamicstring = 'שֶׁמֶן';
    $word_strlen = mb_strlen($dynamicstring, 'UTF-8');
    $newstring = mb_substr($dynamicstring, ($word_strlen-2), $word_strlen, 'UTF-8');

    echo mb_strlen($dynamicstring);
    echo '<br>';
    echo htmlspecialchars($newstring);
?>
```

Comment: Again, as I say in another comment, I have already using this. I'm not using SQL so its not the problem. I have trying to do what that you say with mb_substr and its not worked.. I need the **last** 2 characters

Answer (score 0):

use  mb_substr($string, 0, 3, 'UTF-8'); method and instead of UTF-8 specify the correct format for hebrew language

Comment: I have trying this and its not working (additionally I need the last 2 characters so it need to be: $string, -4, 0, 'UTF-8'

Answer (score 0):

Neither `substr()` nor `mb_substr()` knows about character marks or letters. `substr()` simply looks at the number of bytes and `mb_substr()` looks at the number of codepoints. Since both character marks and letters use a single codepoint each, there's no way for `mb_substr()` to distinguish between them.

What you can do instead is use a regular expression:

```
if (preg_match('/\X\X$/u', $dynamicstring, $match)) {
    $newstring = $match[0];
}
```

or

```
$newstring = preg_replace('/^.*?(\X\X)$/us', '$1', $dynamicstring);
```

Using either of these in your program outputs the last two letters of שֶׁמֶן:

> מֶן

Each `\X` will match a letter plus all immediately following marks. The `/u` option at the end of the expression is to switch on Unicode mode (UTF-8), otherwise it won't be able to recognise Hebrew codepoints.

If you want to use the single line `preg_replace()` version, you must add `^.*?` to the start of the regex pattern to match all characters from the start of the input string up to the next pattern. The `*?` instead of `*` is to make it non-greedy, otherwise it will take part of the next sequence as well. The `/s` option is only needed if the input has line breaks in it, to allow `.` to match all characters including line breaks, otherwise it can be left out.

I recommend looking at Regular-Expressions.info, especially [the section on PHP](https://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html) and [the section on Unicode](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html).